# Large data transfer using WCF

Tags: wcf

I am in a project where i have to transfer large data atonce back and forth between source and client using wcf service in between.Which is the bect option to transfer data as a DATASET, XML, ARRAY OF OBJECTS or is there any other option?

Comment: Is there something wrong with Simons answer? If not, you should accept it. If it's not satisfying, please comment on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use WCF Streaming. Here is a link for more information: [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)