# Error invoking a web reference service which receives a long list of objects

Tags: wcf, web-services

I'm invoking a service on a Web Reference which receives a list of objects `List<T>`
It works well list up to approximately 13000, but when the length of the list is over 13000 and the service is invoked it throws the following error:
***The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.***

I also had an error very similar (***The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.***) on a service which receives a string and returns a long list of objects (as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498888/service-reference-return-value-size-issue)), I've solved it in the web.config, but it doesn't solve the error for the service which receives the List as a parameter, it only works to be able to return long lists of objects

I have this in the bindings:

```
<binding name="customBasicHttp" closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
    sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferSize="67108864" maxBufferPoolSize="67108864" 
    maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864" messageEncoding="Text" 
    textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="67108864"
        maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="5242880"
        maxNameTableCharCount="67108864" />
    <security mode="None" />
</binding>
```

And this in the behaviors:

```
<behavior name="EndpointBehaviour">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
</behavior>
```

I need to be able to send a long list of objects as a parameter to a service in a web reference

Comment: You need to use WCF streaming to transfer large data from/to WCF services as it is mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304035/large-data-transfer-using-wcf

Comment: FYI, you're not using a "Web Reference". You're using a "Service Reference". Don't worry - that's the right thing to do, you're just using the wrong term.

Comment: Have you increased quotas on the client side too?

Answer (score 0):

What if you split your large array of object in for example 3 or 4 parts and each time send one of them via web service?